# Unable to move one group to different group

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am working on one of the app UI project where I need to move one group to different group in illustrator.Reference screen shot is added.

However when I want to move this group to another group, for some reason I am unable to do it.

[image: Layers screen shot with groups]

Basically I want to move **contextmenu** group to **address-2** group but illustrator shows disabled state while moving.Even I can't ungroup contextmenu.

Can anyone help what I m doing wrong?
What does small triangle in right top of contextmenu indicate?

Comment: Are you **certain** they are both merely groups? They've been renamed so its hard to tell... you can't move a layer or sublayer into a group.... *guessing* that `contextmenu` is a layer, not a group.

Comment: I have first created symbol of context menu and then drag and drop it into another document and then break the symbol.I don't know whether it's a sublayer or group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, only Layers and Sublayers will *not* move into a group due to hierarchy. The levels being `Layer -> Sublayer -> Group`. So, a Layer or Sublayer will never move into a group.

Chances are `contextmenu` is a layer/sublayer.

Based upon comments under the question, if it was a symbol which has been "broken", then it's most likely a sublayer, and sublayers can't be moved into groups.

To get around this... Select everything in `contextmenu` and group it, that will create a new `<Group>` in the layers panel which then *can* be moved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't move an existing group into the other group. However, you can select both of the groups and group them together one more time.
Also, it's a good practice to re-arrange objects into several layers. It will make your project more efficient and better organized.

What's the function of the triangle next to the red rectangle? - It basically says that all elements of context menu are selected and active.

Comment: Ok but why triangle doesn't come after selecting address-2?

Comment: uhm.. you **can** move a group into another group. This is incorrect.